# nested KVM virtual machines: Andoid Studio 4.0 AVD inside Debian 10 VM

Tags: android-virtual-device, kvm, android-studio-4.0

I want to run Android Studio 4.0 including the emulator for Android Virtual Devices inside a virtual machine with Debian 10.4 as guest-OS (AVD and Debian-VM are qemu/KVM/libvirt VMs).

Possible reasons for such a scenario: Being able to copy and/or transfer the whole guest-OS VM to other host-OS machines, e. g.:

- cloning an Android development environment for participants of an Android development training or
- transfer an Android development environment after installing necessary components (SDK, emulator image, gradle, ...) on a machine with internet connectivity to a machine with no internet connectivity or
- update or change of the host-OS while keeping the Android development environment

The real CPU of the host-OS is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz. The host OS is currently also Debian 10.4.

The guest-OS KVM VM has 4 virtual CPUs and 8 GB RAM.

I have set "options kvm_intel nested=1" in /etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf of the host-OS.

I have mainly used default values when creating the guest-OS Debian KVM VM and when creating the AVD.

The Android Studio event log shows some error messages:

- SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system
- failed to create drawable
- Failed to create Vulkan instance

but the AVD boots Android and shows the Android GUI.

The problem is, that the emulated Android is too slow for being usable for testing Android apps. E. g. it takes multiple seconds before it reacts to a simple text input. I also observed high CPU usage inside the guest OS.

I also did some unsuccessful tries before with:

- an Intel Core 2 real CPU -> nested VMs not supported yet
- AVD KVM VM inside a VirtualBox guest-OS VM -> Android Studio event log error "KVM: injection failed, MSI lost (Operation not permitted)"

How can I speed up the performance of the AVD inside the KVM-VM by certain configuration options? Or is this scenario of an AVD KVM VM running inside a Debian KVM VM in principal slow?